# Refreshing JWT access token with refresh token within single middleware function on a post route

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, middleware

I'm trying to learn `JWT` authentication in `express` and one thing that I'm came across [this code from Github](https://github.com/manosriram-youtube/jwt-auth/blob/59c0ffe36e/index.js)

that this guy has initialised an `middleware` function to authenticate and check expiry of access token as per below:

```
app.post("/protected", auth, (req, res) => {
    return res.json({ message: "Protected content!" });
})
```

```
async function auth(req, res, next) {
    let token = req.headers["authorization"];
    token = token.split(" ")[1]; //Access token

    jwt.verify(token, "access", async (err, user) => {
        if (user) {
            req.user = user;
            next();
        } else if (err.message === "jwt expired") {
            return res.json({
                success: false,
                message: "Access token expired"
            });
        } else {
            console.log(err);
            return res
                .status(403)
                .json({ err, message: "User not authenticated" });
        }
    });
}
```

and a separate route for refreshing the `access token` with the help of `refresh token`

```
app.post("/refresh", (req, res, next) => {
    const refreshToken = req.body.token;
    if (!refreshToken || !refreshTokens.includes(refreshToken)) {
        return res.json({ message: "Refresh token not found, login again" });
    }

    // If the refresh token is valid, create a new accessToken and return it.
    jwt.verify(refreshToken, "refresh", (err, user) => {
        if (!err) {
            const accessToken = jwt.sign({ username: user.name }, "access", {
                expiresIn: "20s"
            });
            return res.json({ success: true, accessToken });
        } else {
            return res.json({
                success: false,
                message: "Invalid refresh token"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

So, my question is how secure it is and how can I create single middleware function that could do both authentication and refreshing access token without hitting the `app.post('/refresh')` as in my view it wouldn't be a smooth experience to deal with it in frontend API management within react

**Edit**

My middleware seems to work well but it doesn't identify the wrong refresh token and then actually getting worked on protected route

```
app.post('/home', authenticateUser, (req, res) => {
    res.send('welcome');
});

async function authenticateUser(req, res, next) {
    let token = req.headers['authorization'];
    token = token.split(' ')[1];

    jwt.verify(token, JWT_AUTH_TOKEN, async (err, phone) => {
        if (phone) {
            req.phone = phone;
            next();
        } else if (err) {
            const refreshToken = req.body.refreshToken;
            if (!refreshToken || !refreshTokens.includes(refreshToken)) {
                return res.json({ message: 'Refresh token not found, login again' });
            } else {
                jwt.verify(refreshToken, JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN, (err, phone) => {
                    if (!err) {
                        const accessToken = jwt.sign({ phone }, JWT_AUTH_TOKEN, { expiresIn: '30s' });
                        return res.json({ success: true, accessToken });
                        
                    } else {
                        return res.json({
                            success: false,
                            message: 'Invalid refresh token'
                        });
                    }
                    next();
                });
            }
        } else {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(403).json({ err, message: 'User not authenticated' });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: they/he is just avoiding sending refresh token each time, so it has to hit `/refresh` after it fails. If you don't mind sending the refresh token each time in a header etc you can indeed do a single middleware which refreshes the token after validating the refresh is good once you get a `if (err.name == 'TokenExpiredError') {` etc each to own, but all JWT is insecure if not done over HTTPS.. then whether you send two tokens is upto you

Comment: @LawrenceCherone can you please tell me what this means : `if (err.name == 'TokenExpiredError') {` and also I've updated my own middleware function. Any suggestion where should I made changes? it doesn't return back to private route and don't identity the invalid refresh tokens

Comment: err is in your code, you should only be issuing a new token if its `TokenExpiredError`, there could be other reasons it could fail verify(), like tampering or invalid etc. I cant see from your code where you're going to POST `req.body.refreshToken`? That won't be defined on every route

Comment: also, you should send it back as a header so the client can pick up the new token without it affecting the current payload.. should all be done in headers